# URL Routing for CMS

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, url-routing

I am developing a CMS that stores user content in a database table like this:

```
----------------------------------------
PageId   | PageTitle(Unique) |  Content 
----------------------------------------
1        | PageOne           | ...
2        | PageTwo           | ...
3        | PageThree         | ...
4        | PageFour          | ...
```

Now I have an aspx page "SitePageFactory.aspx" at root that serves dynamic content when a querystring is passed to it, suppose /SitePageFactory.aspx?pgid=1 is passed then it serves the content for PageOne.

The concept above is working fine.

Now I want to put a step further by adding dynamic routes to this application and modify **/SitePageFactory.aspx?pgid=1** to **/PageOne.aspx** but **unable to do it at root level**.

**NOTE:** Currently I am able to perform routing like **/SitePageFactory/PageOne.aspx** but I want the results at the root level.

Thanks.

Comment: routes.MapRoute("", "{path}", new { controller = "CMS", action = "Index", path = UrlParameter.Optional }); worked for me ... maps every initial request to the Index action on the CMS controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ASP.NET Routing to accomplish this.

Routing let's you map an url like: www.mysite.com/pages/pageone to an aspx page. The different parts in your url can be mapped to route parameters that you can access in your aspx.

[Here is the MSDN documentation](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc668201.aspx&ei=vrEjT6jcPIKk-gbZla2-CA&usg=AFQjCNFjNNOphHEfp1qCeFbwB1PWbh4--A) for routing.

You can add the folowing route:

```
routes.MapRoute("ViewPage",
                "<PageName>",
                new { controller = "Page", action = "ViewPage" }
```

This will map the url www.yourdomain/ to the Page controllers ViewPage method.

Comment: Ya I already knew about it but the problem is how to perform routing at root level, for ex. see www.guidetoindiatour.com, the routing works here and generates links like http://guidetoindiatour.com/pg/21/Home.aspx where pg/21/Home.aspx works as pg/{PageId}/{PageTitle}.aspx, and I want something like http://guidetoindiatour.com/Home.aspx

Comment: Ya it is working, actually I didn't stated that I am using WebForms, by the way I can convert the solution accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Hi,

Can you share your code as I'm also developing the same thing using webforms.

Comment: @SherryAnnHernandez what do you need? :)

Comment: The code when using in webforms. I have these pages http://www.domain.com/default.aspx?lang=ar&propertyID=1 and I want to route it in www.domain.com/ar/dubai-property-1